# event.pageX - Use jQuery Event in a function not bound through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a table, and when the user clicks on each cell, some details should appear in a small popup div that appears where the user clicked. I'm using jQuery, but not to bind the function to the onClick event.

```
function detailPopup(cell, event, groupName, groupID, ...)
{
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   newDiv.id = "detailPop" + groupID;
   newDiv.className = "priceDetailPopup";
   newDiv.innerHTML = "<p>" + groupName + "</p>"; // more will go here
   $(newDiv).click(function()
       {
           $(this).fadeOut("fast").remove();
       }
   );
   $("#main").append(newDiv);
   $(newDiv).css({"left" : event.pageX, "top" : event.pageY}).fadeIn("fast");
}
```

Everything is working wonderfully in FF, Safari, and Chrome. In IE, it all works except that the detail div appears below the table. **event.pageX/Y aren't working.** I know jQuery will fix those for IE if I bind the function through jQuery like this:

```
$(cell).click(function(e) { ... e.pageX ... })
```

But I can't do that. (I don't think I can - if you do, please explain how I can get six variables into that function without having to use non-xhtml tags in the cell.)

Is there a way to have jQuery "fix" the event object without binding the function through jQuery? $JQuery.fixEvent(event); or something? I can't find any reference to doing so on their site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
e = jQuery.event.fix(e);  //you should rename your event parameter to "e"
```

I found the `fix` function by searching through the jQuery source code.

Alternatively, you could use this to get the mouse coordinates *without* jQuery...

```
var posx = 0;
var posy = 0;
if (!e) var e = window.event;
if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
  posx = e.pageX;
  posy = e.pageY;
}
else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
  posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
```

Via PPK: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Comment: This works, but I'm hoping there's a way to use jQuery's existing functionality.

Comment: That's it! Two great answers in one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This blog post seems to be relevant: http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/2009/04/10/jquery-bind-data/

Seems it's just `jQuery("#selector").bind("click", {name: "barney"}, clickHandler);`, then `e.data.name` to access it in the event.

Answer (score -1):

You might find that the issue you're facing is not a positioning issue at all. Based on the syntax you posted, you may be experiencing an IE bug relating to the use of the CSS ID selector.

```
$("#main").append(newDiv);
```

If IE doesn't recognize the "#main" element, the append() function will not work correctly.   IE (pre-v7) has spotty support for the ID (#) selector. Instead try:

```
$('div[id="main"]').append(newDiv);
```

Try this and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't do it. event.pageX/Y are definitely undefined. I have confirmed that by alerting them out.

Comment: Using the ID is the easiest possible way to get an element, and it's been supported since antique versions of IE.  There's no way that IE screwed this up.  Either provide a link that backs up your claim, or I am calling BS!

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't supported. I said it had spotty support.  And I don't presume that the sample code the asker posts is the exact code from the project. (usually it's cleaned up for public display and simplification) http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/idselector  "In Internet Explorer 6, an ID selector is ignored unless it’s the last ID selector in the simple selector". The symptoms here seemed consistent with the element being drawn inline and not "attached" to an existing element. It was worth a shot.  Sorry it wasn't the simple fix I was hoping for you, Scott.

Comment: And, Josh, voting my response down without giving me an opportunity to defend myself doesn't feel very friendly.  If your goal is to offend, I think you'll do well.

Comment: Not trying to offend anybody!  That link has nothing to do with jQuery.